# Is a formal grammar of a formal language a formal language?

Tags: grammar-formalism

From http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Meta

> In linguistics, a grammar is considered as being expressed in a metalanguage, language that operates on a higher level in order to describe properties of the plain language (and not itself).

I wonder if a formal grammar of a formal language is a metalanguage of the formal language?

Comment: Yes, of course. It's turtles all the way up.

Comment: Not all grammars are written that way. Some just use terminology to describe the grammar. But a grammar using NSM would be.

Comment: @curiousdannii: I am talking about formal grammars for formal languages. Not natural ones.

Comment: @jlawler: Thanks. What is the "metalanguage" in the quote "a grammar is considered as being expressed in a metalanguage"? It doesn't seem to be the "grammar".

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is about formal languages rather than natural languages, constructed languages or linguistic theory.

Comment: @curiousdannii: I beg you to let it stay. Thanks.

Comment: It's just my opinion, I don't know if others would agree or not. No hard feelings!

Comment: Which formal languages are you talking about? Lojban? COBOL? Klingon? Second-order quantified predicate calculus? Legal English? `yacc` + `lex`? There are a lot of things that are called "formal languages".

Comment: @jlawler Any formal language. It is defined as a set of strings over an alphabet. http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Formal_language#Definition

Comment: You hafta have at least one actual example of the species, before you can talk about its properties. They may not exist, you know.

Answer (score 2):

Your question is confused. You confuse a grammar (an entity) with its expression (a language). So by very definition, the grammar of any language (formal or informal) is expressed in a metalanguage.

However, the difference between "formal" and natural languages is that a grammar of a natural language is always expressed in a metalanguage which is a part of natural language in the broadest possible sense (point made strongly by Gadamer in his Hermeneutics). In this, the Wikipedia quote is not very accurate because metalanguage can very easily be applied to itself.

However, a grammar of a formal language is more likely to be expressed by a different order language. Even a simple A -> B contains a symbol not of that language. However, this all depends on a metaphor of thinking about formal languages as language, in the first place. It's very useful but needn't be taken to extremes.